# How to press a button when while loop is running?

Tags: c#

I am working in a machine vision project.In my project i am using camera for print inspection. 
In my application i am using one picturebox for displaying a image on screen and two buttons.In two buttons one button for live display and another for fullscreen.With the livedisplay button I am displaying image in picturebox in a while loop. in the same time while process in while loop i have to press fullscreen button. but I can't press fullscreen button because while the loop is running it doesn't allow me to push any of the buttons of the form. (The loop is a while) Why is this happening? How can I click this button while the loop is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be rather than running a while loop; use a timer with some interval and on timer tick update the image in picture box. You can start the timer when user clicks on Liveupdate button. You can keep the interval very low(e.g. 100ms) so that your updates will give feeling of being LIVE.  This will give some interval in between two updates when application can take input for other user action like other button click.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the wonderful world of multi-threading. You need to put your while loop on a separate thread, so your UI remains responsive. Threading is a long, deep concept, and there are a million ways to do it.

Probably the path is least resistance is to use the BackgroundWorker threading model. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I edited the link. I originally gave the wrong link (for Silverlight), fixed, but not well enough, apparently. Anyway, should be working now.

Comment: And trust me, even though it might look a little complicated at first, the BackgroundWorker model is a pretty simple way to multi-thread your application. And it's a good introduction into more advanced multi-threading concepts.